# Oracle XE 18c database size limitation

Tags: oracle, database-size, oracle-18c

According to official Oracle documentation available at https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/xe/faq.html it has limitations:

> What are the resource limits for Oracle Database XE Oracle Database XE
> supports up to:
>
> 3 Pluggable Databases
>
> 2 CPUs for foreground processes
>
> 2GB of RAM (SGA and PGA combined)
>
> 12GB of user data on disk (irrespective of compression factor)

When running SQL

```
select 
  TABLESPACE_NAME "Tablspace",  
   FILE_NAME "Filename",  
   BYTES/1024/1024 "Size MB"
from 
  SYS.DBA_DATA_FILES;
```

I have the result:

```
Tablspace                      Filename                                                   Size MB
------------------------------ ------------------------------------------------------- ----------
USERS                          C:\ORACLEXE18C\PRODUCT\18.0.0\ORADATA\XE\USERS01.DBF         11,25
UNDOTBS1                       C:\ORACLEXE18C\PRODUCT\18.0.0\ORADATA\XE\UNDOTBS01.DBF        4230
SYSTEM                         C:\ORACLEXE18C\PRODUCT\18.0.0\ORADATA\XE\SYSTEM01.DBF         8630
SYSAUX                         C:\ORACLEXE18C\PRODUCT\18.0.0\ORADATA\XE\SYSAUX01.DBF          900
```

### Question

Which files does Oracle consider to validate the maximum size 12GB? Because if you make the sum of the 4 TableSpace I have already passed 12 GB.

Answer (score 1):

The datafiles are used. If you are over size, you won’t notice this until you stop the database and try to start it again. Weird errors will appear like invalid size errors.